# Erlang Cowboy and Ranch acceptors

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, cowboy, beam

How do I determine the right number of Ranch acceptors to use in an OTP application? I've noticed that Elixir Phoenix applications start with a default of 100, but there's no real explanation as to why.

In basic tests, 1 single acceptors is appears to work fine for a basic application, which is at least evidence enough to suggest that a acceptors does not match 1 to 1 for each client connection.

For the record the official docs suggest the following:

> By default Ranch will use 10 acceptor processes. Their role is to
>   accept connections and spawn a connection process for every new
>   connection.
>
> This number can be tweaked to improve performance. A good number is
>   typically between 10 or 100 acceptors. You must measure to find the
>   best value for your application.

Which does kind of explain what they are, but is still a little vague on detail.

So how exactly are we meant to use them?

Comment: You are asking multiple questions here. How do you determine the right number, and how to use them. Like the documentation says, you just need to measure your application to figure out the proper sweet spot for the number of acceptor processes.

Comment: All acceptors are listening on one listen socket. I set them to the number of cores I have. you can use erlang:system_info(schedulers) to set it dynamically.